# What affects the text color in Google Earth?

Tags: 11.04, interface, usability, colors, google-earth

The text color in Google Earth (installed via [Google's package](http://www.google.com/earth/download/ge/)) has recently changed to become unreadable:

[image: Unreadable text color]

It hasn't always been this way, but I don't know what I did that caused it to change.

What settings are responsible for the text color in Google Earth?

Comment: Did you change your theme? Google Earth uses QT so it will be something in QT's theme settings (possibly poor emulation of some GTK theme) that causes that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Restoring the default settings in KDE System Settings resolved the problem, so the setting must have been related to a color theme I had applied earlier.